# Get available space fails

Tags: android

Up to now, I have been querying for available space in the following manner :

```
StatFs stats;
long lBlockSize, lBlockCount;
long lTotal = 1;

stats = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("Documents").getAbsolutePath());

lBlockCount = (long)stats.getAvailableBlocksLong();
lBlockSize = (long)stats.getBlockSizeLong();
lTotal = lBlockCount * lBlockSize;

return lTotal;
```

However, with Android 9 this would appear to be failing (reported to me by a user).

Has something major changed ?

Answer (score 0):

With Android 9 I don't think there was any major change BUT with Android 10 there was a major change to start the introduction of Scoped Storage, where you might not have direct access to the file system any more. (With Android 11 Google have said that this type of file access won't work any more).

See https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped

Comment: This sounds scary as it appears to say that apps cannot store app specific, non-media, proprietary files on the tablet anymore.  This can't be right, can it ?

Comment: You can store any app specific file, just they are private to your app OR you need to use Storage Access Framework if you want to store them in a public location visible to other Apps (Which will put then in the "Download" folder if you only have the default Content Provider installed). There is some "non documented" features that allow you to use the MediaStore API instead.